# My Cloud Run Service suddenly returning NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've had a working service running on GCP Cloud Run for months.  I recently deployed a new version, and started getting NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID from the service.  I rolled back the deployed version to an earlier working version but get the same result.  Google provides little if any useful info on how to resolve this so I am stumped.

I have a FastAPI based service that has been working for several months.  I deploy it to Cloud run via Cloud Build. I deployed a version this morning and everything was working fine.  I deployed a new version and started getting these privacy errors.  I rolled back my deployed version but am still getting the errors and can't reach my service.

Comment: Did you SSL certificate just run out?  This can also happen if there is no SSL and  your links are actually prefixed with http  but the update somehow is using  https if that makes sense.  If you rolled it back nothing has changed, then maybe your cert ran out and you just need to renew it ?

Comment: From my understanding, Google Cloud Run manages its own SSL certificates

Comment: I figured as much, so that is strange.   Sounds like a settings got changed for the upgrade that rolling back didn't undo?  Not sure what to tell you here, good luck!

Comment: That problem is most likely an issue with your computer and not with Cloud Run. There are sites to validate your site's certificate such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ Double-check the date and time zone on your computer and reboot your system. Edit your post with details on the OS, browser, and date of last system update.

Comment: I think you're right - thanks for this.  I was able to reach the site just fine from another device.

Comment: just encountered the same, not only me but also my colleague, `restart` helped

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is only a partial answer, but I am having the same issue. I have a container that runs fine on other cloud services (e.g. Scaleway). I have an upstream proxy with self-signed certificate. I've trusted my self-signed root CA and proxy CA on the container machine. No verification errors, except on Google Cloud Run jobs.

My guess as to what is happening is that outgoing requests are being proxied through a VPC, much like on a corporate network. My next step (I will try to follow up here, but have to get this job finished) is to download the certificate chain into the container using openssl s_client, grab Google's private self-signed CA, and either do that dynamically when the container runs, or just bake it into the container.

Meanwhile, I just have to turn verification off until that's working, but my guess is it's Google's VPC self-signed certificate, because I don't have this issue on other cloud providers as stated.

EDIT: I just realized you may be referring to incoming requests, but it's likely the same issue. Google has a (SOCKS proxy?) cert between Cloud Run and the internet, perhaps for both inbound and outbound traffic.